# PHP (or jQuery, if need be): Output related MySQL records from other tables as JSON?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have two tables:

Table 1:

```
Make       Model 1 ID      Model 2 ID      Model 3 ID
----       ----------      ----------      ----------
Ford       1               4               7
Chevrolet  2               3               5
Dodge      6               8               9
```

Table 2:

```
ID         Model            Engine
----       -----            ------
1          F-150            Triton V8
2          Silverado        Vortec V8
3          Corvette         LS9 V8
4          Fusion           Duratec I4
5          Camaro           LSA V8
6          Ram              Hemi V8
7          Mustang          Modular V8
8          Grand Caravan    Pentastar V6
9          Challenger       Hemi V8
```

I want the linked data to be outputted (is that how you say it? I'm a bit of a noob to programming terminology. Sorry.) as JSON using PHP, so that the output looks like this (or something extremely similar if my JSON syntax is wrong):

```
 {
  [
   {
    "make": "Ford",  
    "models": 
     [ 
      { 
      "ID": "1",
      "info": 
         {
         "model": "F-150",
         "engine": "Triton V8", 
         }
      },
      { 
      "ID": "4",
      "info": 
         {
         "model": "Fusion",
         "engine": "Duratec I4", 
         }
      },
      { 
      "ID": "7",
      "info": 
         {
         "model": "Mustang",
         "engine": "Triton V8", 
         }
      },
     ] 
   },
   {
    "make": "Chevrolet",  
    "models": 
     [ 
      { 
      "ID": "2",
      "info": 
         {
         "model": "Silverado",
         "engine": "Vortec V8", 
         }
      },
      { 
      "ID": "3",
      "info": 
         {
         "model": "Corvette",
         "engine": "LS9 V8", 
         }
      },
      { 
      "ID": "5",
      "info": 
         {
         "model": "Camaro",
         "engine": "", 
         }
      },
     ] 
   },   {
    "make": "Dodge",  
    "models": 
     [ 
      { 
      "ID": "6",
      "info": 
         {
         "model": "Ram",
         "engine": "Hemi V8", 
         }
      },
      { 
      "ID": "8",
      "info": 
         {
         "model": "Grand Caravan",
         "engine": "Pentastar V6", 
         }
      },
      { 
      "ID": "9",
      "info": 
         {
         "model": "Challenger",
         "engine": "Hemi V8", 
         }
      },
     ] 
   }
  ]
}
```

The question is, how do you do this using PHP? Thanks for taking the time reading until the end of this rather long post, and thanks in advance for trying to come up with a solution.

If you want to suggest a solution using jQuery, that works too.

Comment: You create a PHP array, populate it with the data from the DB like you want it and then convert it to JSON with `json_encode`.

Comment: You make an array, convert it to json, echo it and die `header("Content-type: application/json"); echo json_encode($array); die;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your database is wrong. Try this structure instead:

```
MakeID Make
------ ----
1      Ford
2      Chevrolet
3      Dodge

ModelID MakeID Model          Engine
------- ------ -------------- ------
1       1      F-150          Triton V8
2       2      Silverado      Vortec V8
3       2      Corvette       LS9 V8
4       1      Fusion         Duratec I4
5       2      Camaro         LSA V8
6       3      Ram            Hemi V8
7       1      Mustang        Modular V8
8       3      Grand Caravan  Pentastar V6
9       3      Challenger     Hemi V8
```

Now you can do something like this:

```
$sql = mysql_query("select * from `table1` join `table2` using (`MakeID`)");
$out = Array();
while($car = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    if( !isset($out[$car['MakeID']])) {
        $out[$car['MakeID']] = Array("make"=>$car['Make'],"models"=>Array());
    }
    $out[$car['MakeID']]['models'][] = Array(
        "ID"=>$car['ModelID'],
        "info":Array(
            "model"=>$car['Model'],
            "engine"=>$car['Engine']
        )
    );
}
$out = array_values($out);
echo json_encode($out);
```